# MS Access PHP Connection using PDO "could not find driver" error

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, database-connection

I am unable to connect to my Access database with the following code. I receive a "could not find driver" error. Can anyone offer a solution?

```
<?php

$mdbFileName = realpath('Project1.accdb');  

try {

    $dbh = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};Dbq=$mdbFileName",'','');
    if (!$dbh)
        echo 'Failed3';
    else
        echo 'Success3';
    }
catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    } 
odbc_close($dbh);

?>
```

Comment: For the record, your problem was probably just a missing space: `*.mdb, *.accdb`. However, the approach in your answer is a much better method for dealing with an Access database on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was to use a COM object and an OLEDB connection instead of PDO and an ODBC connection:

```
<?php

$dbh = new COM('ADODB.Connection') or die('Cannot start ADO'); 

 $dbh->Open('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=Project1.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;');

    if (!$dbh)
        echo 'Failed3';
    else
        echo 'Success3'; 

?>
```

Comment: +1 This is a much better alternative to using PDO_ODBC when dealing with an Access database on a Windows server.